# Can I select a 32bit JRE to run a Talend Job when Studio is on 64bit JDK/JRE?

Tags: talend

I'm trying to access an ancient history JDBC driver which is not pure-java and requires 32 bit DLLs.

Talend 6.5.1 is set up using the 64 bit Java 1.8 on Windows 64bit.

I note that in Talend I can configure multiple JREs, but I cant find anywhere to select which one a job should run on.

I presume once I've build the .jar file I can run the job on the 32bit JRE, but I'd like to be able to run the job from the studio in the 32bit JRE. It appears to be starting a new JVM to run the job, so this should theoretically  be possible, I'd have thought, but I just can't see how to select this.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, before I run out of hair to pull out?

Thanks! 
Screwtape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there's no way to simply set another JRE to execute jobs from the studio. The JRE that is used by Talend executable at startup is the one that is used to run the jobs; Talend just ignores any JRE you set in `Preferences > Java > Installed JREs` (even if you set it as default).
What you can do though is switch to the 32bit executable of Talend when you want to run your job in 32bit mode:

`TOS_DI-win32-x86.exe`

You can force this executable to run a specific version of java by changing its ini file :

```
TOS_DI-win32-x86.ini
```

And adding the path to your jre at the beginning of the file like this:

```
-vm 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_161\bin\javaw.exe
```

Comment: Unfortunately Talend ESB 6.5 doesn't have a Win32 exe file, and trying to call the x86_84 version with the -vm to a 32bit JVM doesn't seem to work, somewhat unsurprisingly. Thanks anyway. I've accepted as it would work for older Talend versions.